# Puedo validar la contraseña de un usuario tipo administrador cuando ya me he logueado con otro tipo de usuario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp, identity

Espero puedan orientarme a qué temas consultar o saber si es posible lo que pregunto.

El usuario laragutz es de tipo "capturista", es responsable de realizar los registros de datos nuevos, sin embargo tiene la posibilidad de editar un registro cuando haya cometido algún error, si y solo si, ha proporcionado correctamente la contraseña del administrador en el botón de editar. [image: Ver imagen de ejemplo]

¿Es posible usar Identity o AsignInManager para validar la contraseña proporcionada sin cerrar la sesión del usuario laragutz como capturista?
No se requiere cerrar la sesión, puesto que se pretende no dejar de responsabilizar al usuario encargado de registrar y haber cometido el error, ya que se lleva una tabla como historial de movimiento, tipo bitácora de acciones.

Con agradecimiento.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta es buena, y esta bien estructurada.. lo que me extraña es si no es un riesgo de seguridad que sepa la pass de admin.. que sentido tendria eso?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu consejos y realmente es lógico lo que preguntas. El argumento que sostienen es por que "mentalmente" no quieren quitarle la responsabilidad del capturista en estar atento a lo que captura. Asi si la edición por error se presenta, quedarám registrado con el usuario del capturista y no del administrador.

Comment: El usuario @VDWWD fue quien me compartió una sugerencia y fue muy útil... usar UserManager.CheckPassword. Comparto la respuesta por si llegasé a ver alguien más con la misma duda a futuro.